# SSH config using wrong key?

Tags: git, ssh

I started in a new job today, where they use bitbucket, and they have created me an account using my new work email address.

However, when I pasted my SSH key in, Bitbucket complained that the key was already in use (my personal account), so I had to set up another key.

My SSH config looked like this, but it didn't work and seemed to pick up the wrong key:

```
Host work
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User git
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_work
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

then I tried `git clone work:path/to/some.git` but got "could not read from repo."

I had to edit away my normal `id_rsa` before it would work, so now it looks like this:

```
Host *
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User git
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_work
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your initial config file (the one with `Host work` and `Host *`), you can do a

```
ssh -Tv work
```

You will see what key is actually used. If it is `id_rsa`, that means what is specified in `Host *` takes precedence over `Host work`.

If you want to [use your personal key for everything *except* work](https://superuser.com/a/732274/141), you would need to [use a pattern](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5#PATTERNS):

```
Host * !work
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```